# MySql - MySql server thinks there is no password when its provided in the URL

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc, mariadb, slick

In the image, you can see that the password is provided in the URL but the exception says access denied because password is not provided.
Please advise.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html

I believe that your JDBC connection string is specified incorrectly as per the spec. It should be of the format

jdbc:mysql://sandy:secret@[myhost1:1111,myhost2:2222]/db (as per the example above)

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I changed and I get a different error: https://imgur.com/a/XhFNTKt. Please see if you see anything wrong.

Comment: How are you building the string? You might need to url encode your password depending on whether you have odd characters in your password

Comment: Even with the encoding I get the same error. I have uploaded a new pic to the previous post. The only special character is '!' at the end. All the other characters are between [a-Z, 0-9].

Comment: There is no code. Database address is read from a props file. I have added that too to the original post.

Comment: Where I'm a bit confused about your question is that it looks like you're using the slick library, and http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/database.html If you look the examples for slick, you shouldn't even need to build the jdbc connection string

(more examples) http://www.hashbangbin.sh/posts/getting-started-scala-%2B-slick-%2B-postgresql-mysql/

Comment: We connect to database using the second method in the first link that you posted using 'Database.forURL(url, driver)'. For that I need the build (or read) the url. I have updated the post again with our database creation.

Comment: I can't debug with what you provided...I would need to see the source code of the scala/java application that is throwing the error. It looks like a parsing error, either something is being split or truncated. Sorry for not being of further help